# MySQL HIGHEST/LOWEST 5 from a ROW of data

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I have the following query:

```
SELECT AVG(q1) AS q1, AVG (q2) AS q2, AVG(q3) AS q3, AVG(q4) AS q4, AVG(q5) AS q5 FROM tresults_acme

q1    q2    q3    q4    q5
8.23  5.23  7.65  8.00  7.99
```

This query brings back a single row of data, headed q1, q2, q3, q4, q5 - is it possible in MySQL to just show the Highest two (q1 & q4) or Lowest two (q2 & q3) - if not in MySQL can it be done via PHP?

Thanks in advance,

Homer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914063/how-to-get-the-top-n-values-of-each-column-in-mysql

Comment: @Haim I don't think this is a question about `limits` - Homer's query only returns one row

Comment: Hi all, apologies I should have been clearer in my description - is it possible for MySQL to return the highest and/or lowest form that singele row of data?  As you rightly say Jack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a procedure, but here is a pure SQL way of doing it:

```
    select greatest(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5) as highest_1,
           least( greatest(q1,q2,q3,q4),
                  greatest(q1,q2,q3,q5),
                  greatest(q1,q2,q4,q5),
                  greatest(q1,q3,q4,q5),
                  greatest(q2,q3,q4,q5) ) as highest_2
    from ( SELECT AVG(q1) AS q1, 
                  AVG(q2) AS q2, 
                  AVG(q3) AS q3, 
                  AVG(q4) AS q4, 
                  AVG(q5) AS q5 
           FROM tresults_acme ) t;
```

tested with:

```
create view tresults_acme as select 1 as q1, 2 as q2, 3 as q3, 4 as q4, 5 as q5;
```

result:

```
         highest_1      |     highest_2
    --------------------+--------------------
     5.0000000000000000 | 4.0000000000000000
```

Comment: thanks for this - it does return two numbers - although I'm a little confused as to what this query is doing - would you be good enough to explain a little more so I can understand?